wclGattClient never fires OnConnect event
I have a Windows 11 PC where I'm trying to connect with a BLE device using the wclBluetoothFramework. Everything seems to work OK up until the point where I try to connect. I call wclGattClient.Connect() hoping to see the OnConnect event fired at some stage but it never happens.
The code is below, it's a bit long so I've put it at the bottom of this question. But when it calls wclBluetoothRadio.Discover() that works fine and it finds my device amongst many others, and also has no problem getting its name. But then when it tries to Connect(), nothing happens - the Client_OnConnect event is never fired, and I have a label continuously updating and displaying the State of the client, and it remains at csConnecting. Even if I turn off the device and remove the batteries, nothing ever happens - in this case I'd expect to hit the OnConnect but with an error code.
I'm following the documentation from this page: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm
One other thing - not sure if it's related -  is that when I close the application normally, the process doesn't shut down! I have to kill it afterwards (or press the 'Stop' button in Visual Studio)
Here is my code with a simple WinForm example:
public partial class BleMessing : Form
{
    wclBluetoothManager _manager;
    wclBluetoothRadio _radio;
    wclGattClient _client;

    Timer _statusTimer;

    public BleMessing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radio = GetRadio();

        if (radio == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var res = radio.Discover(10, wclBluetoothDiscoverKind.dkBle);
    }

    private void BleMessing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _manager = new wclBluetoothManager();
        _manager.Open();

        _radio = GetRadio();

        _manager.OnDeviceFound += _manager_OnDeviceFound;
        _manager.OnDiscoveringStarted += _manager_OnDiscoveringStarted;
        _manager.OnDiscoveringCompleted += _manager_OnDiscoveringCompleted;

        _client = new wclGattClient();
        _client.OnConnect += Client_OnConnect;
        _client.OnDisconnect += Client_OnDisconnect;

        _statusTimer = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = 1000
        };

        _statusTimer.Tick += _statusTimer_Tick;
        _statusTimer.Start();

    }

    private void _statusTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblClientConnectionStatus.Visible = false;

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        lblClientConnectionStatus.Text = _client.State.ToString();
        lblClientConnectionStatus.Visible = true;
    }

    private wclBluetoothRadio GetRadio()
    {
        if (_radio != null)
        {
            return _radio;
        }

        if (_manager.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth not found!", "Bluetooth error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < _manager.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_manager[i].Available)
            {
                return _manager[i];
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("No available bluetooth device found!", "Bluetooth error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;

    }

    private void _manager_OnDeviceFound(object sender, wclBluetoothRadio radio, long address)
    {
        var devType = wclBluetoothDeviceType.dtMixed;
        var res = radio.GetRemoteDeviceType(address, out devType);

        // ignore non BLE devices.

        if (devType != wclBluetoothDeviceType.dtBle)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found device {0} but it's not BLE.");
            return;
        }

        lstDevices.Items.Add(new SelectableBleDevice { Address = address, Radio = radio });
    }

    private void _manager_OnDiscoveringCompleted(object sender, wclBluetoothRadio radio, int error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found all devices! Updating the names...", "Search Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        for (int i = 0; i < lstDevices.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var bleDevice = lstDevices.Items[i] as SelectableBleDevice;
            if (bleDevice == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            string name;
            var res = radio.GetRemoteName(bleDevice.Address, out name);
            if (res == wclErrors.WCL_E_SUCCESS)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Address {bleDevice.AddressText} is name {name}");
                bleDevice.Name = name;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting name of Address {bleDevice.AddressText}");
                bleDevice.Name = "error!";
                bleDevice.ErrorCode = res.ToString();
            }

            lstDevices.Items[i] = bleDevice;
        }


        MessageBox.Show("All names updated", "Search Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void _manager_OnDiscoveringStarted(object sender, wclBluetoothRadio radio)
    {
        lstDevices.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var device = GetSelectedDevice();

        _client.Address = device.Address;
        lstDevices.Enabled = false;

        Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to {device}");
        var res = _client.Connect(device.Radio);

        if (res != wclErrors.WCL_E_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to start connection process: {0}", res.ToString()), "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Client_OnDisconnect(object Sender, int Reason)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Client_OnConnect(object Sender, int error)
    {
        var device = GetSelectedDevice();

        if (error == wclErrors.WCL_E_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Connection to {device} Successful!", "Connection Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            device.IsConnected = true;

            device = GetSelectedDevice();

            lstDevices.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show($"Error connecting to {device}: {error.ToString()}", "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        lstDevices.Enabled = true;

    }

    private SelectableBleDevice GetSelectedDevice()
    {
        var item = lstDevices.SelectedItem;

        return (SelectableBleDevice)item;
    }
}

}

Hello, can you try to use the GattClient demo application? Does it work? About app not closed: add wclbiuetoothmanger.Close() call in the FormUnload event handler (you always must close the Bluetooth Manager to release all allocated resources, otherwise internal threads will not be terminated and an app will never exits).

@MikePetrichenko - Thanks - I put in a call to Close(). And if I close the form now after having attempted to Connect() (i.e. with the client state as csConnecting, it gets locked in the call to Close() and doesn't return! Anyway I will try the GattClient demo application as advised.

What is Bluetooth Framework version you use? For .NET Edition you can check it in the wclBluetoothFramework.dll assembly file properties.

@MikePetrichenko - it's 7.9.1

7.9 or 7.19? By the way, what is your device? Not all BLE devices are connectable.

@MikePetrichenko 7.9 - I updated to 7.19 using the demo version and it has gotten rid of the freeze on Close (now it just fires the OnConnected event when I close but with error 0x05000D). Using the GattClient application, it seems kind of hit and miss. It seems to have a hard time just finding the device but when it does, if I have the device in "Pairing Mode", it pairs. It even has occasionally connected automatically! But otherwise, if I just click "Connect", it does nothing, whether it was previously paired or not. If I click "Connect" again, I get error 0x030000.

The Device is a Nonin WristOx 3150

Ok, thank you. So what to do: 1. Make sure that there is no any third party Bluetooth driver extension installed on your PC. It may block BLE communication. 2. Pair with your device (as described the device requires pairing). 3. Find (discover) your device. 4. Check "Connect On Read" check box in the GattClient demo app. Click connect. Once OnConnected event called with 0x00000000 result select "Authentication" (or "Authentication and Encryption" in the drop down box and click Read services. It should returns services from your device.

@MikePetrichenko Thanks for your patience. So with "Connect On Read" set, I get the 0x00 result from the OnConnected event. However, now it just never returns from the ReadServices() call. (This is before it accesses the "Authentication" or "Authentication and Encryption" setting.) BTW I also got 0x05105F from the GetMaxPdu() call, in case that means anything.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
